Как в C# запретить игнорирование возвращаемого значения функции?
Подскажите, как настроить анализатор c#, чтобы он выдавал ошибку компиляции, если возвращаемое значение функции не передаётся переменой?
Т.е., если есть функция
string GetMessage()
{
    return "Hello";
}

, то следующий вызов функции должен не компилироваться
// код
GetMessage();
// код

требуя, чтобы возвращаемое значение было передано в переменную
// код
var message = GetMessage();
// код

или было обозначено явно, что возвращаемое значение игнорируется
// код
_ = GetMessage();
// код


Это надо искать индивидуально в IDE/редакторе кода настройки..... или подключать плагины соответствующие (опять же в этих IDE). Сам C# таким не должен заниматься. В этом нет смысла

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers почитайте их док, может у них есть такая возможность, они хороший анализатор предлагают

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34098

Навешиваем на метод атрибут Pure:
using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;

[Pure]
static string GetMessage()
{
    return "Hello";
}

Будет выдаваться предупреждение (warning) CA1806: Do not ignore method results.
В файле проекта указываем, чтобы этот ворнинг трактовался как ошибка: WarningsAsErrors
<WarningsAsErrors>CA1806</WarningsAsErrors>

Теперь не получится игнорировать возвращаемое значение.

Вместо атрибута Pure можно в файле .editorconfig указать проверку конкретного метода. Additional methods to enforce
dotnet_code_quality.CA1806.additional_use_results_methods = M:MyNamespace.MyType.GetMessage

